# Where to get older bootcamp drivers?

Tags: macbook-pro, windows, bootcamp

I recently partitioned my MBP 15", early 2011 model, so I could run windows. I installed Windows XP and now I have no Wifi. I've installed the bootcamp drivers off CD of Snow Leopard and the disks that came with my machine. No luck, there are no wireless drivers.

What I am planning to do is install Windows 8. How can I get wireless drivers on my XP partition? Or if I download windows 8 on my OSX and make a bootable flash drive and upgrade the os, will I have Wifi that way?

Thanks

Comment: @JashJacob I downloaded the 3.3 drivers but they do not work for some reason in XP.

Answer (score 4):

This [website](http://www.cafe-encounter.net/p682/download-bootcamp-drivers) contains download links for the *latest version* of the Boot Camp WindowsSupport for older devices:

[image: Download Links - Screenshot of table]

For Windows XP, Apple has provided Boot Camp Drivers Update [v2.1](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL830) and [v2.2](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL967) which…

> is intended only for use with Microsoft Windows XP and Microsoft Windows Vista running on a Mac computer using Boot Camp.

Both updates require Boot Camp 2.1. It also notes that…

> This download contains complete copies of Boot Camp Windows XP Drivers (version 2.1). If you have Boot Camp drivers already installed, it will update them.  If you do not have any Boot Camp drivers installed, it will install version 2.1 drivers onto your already installed Windows OS.

This should fix your XP issue, since it contains the latest XP-compatible drivers. If not, your only option will probably be Windows 8 (or Windows 7).

With regard to installing Windows 8, [Boot Camp 5](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5639) brings full Windows 8 support.

Comment: @grarside I have tried the drivers from that page but they only support Windows 7 and won't install. So I found the 3.3 BootCamp Drivers but the installer.exe will not open on Windows XP...no errors nothing happens, not sure why. If I purchase Windows 8, and put the download iso on my portable drive to access the upgrade in XP, do you think that would fix my wifi issue since newer drivers will be installed?

Comment: @twinbornJoint Here's a very old Boot Camp drivers update, compatible with Windows XP: http://support.apple.com/kb/DL967 It requires Boot Camp 2.1, and since you mention the 3.3 Boot Camp drivers, I am unsure whether you can downgrade 3.x to 2.x. Regardless, yes, Windows 8 always uses the latest drivers, and I haven't had any Wi-Fi issues with my Win8 install.

Comment: @twinbornJoint I've added more detail to my answer regarding XP-compatible drivers.

Comment: Thank you kindly for all the information. I've followed everything to a "T" and still does not work. The 2.1 drivers actually load on my XP partition but cannot completed due to compatibility issues with 3.1 installed currently. I guess I will have to purchase Windows 8 and put the install on my flash drive.

Comment: @twinbornJoint No problem :) I presumed that is what would happen. I assume you could *completely* uninstall the 3.x drivers, and then install the 2.x ones, but I've never tried it. I believe it would let you, since it is possible to use Boot Camp without the drivers (you are required to use Windows without the Boot Camp drivers for a certain amount of time so that you can install the drivers in the first place).

Comment: Hehe. It's a bit of work yes but I think I can get it to work. I downloaded SP3 and it installed. Still no wireless drivers. I'm hunting down the wifi chip in Device Manager so perhaps I can download them from the manufacturer website. Windows 8 will install off SP3, wouldn't with no SP. Unfortunately I can't install it without the internet. Doesn't work even with ethernet plugged in, haha. Here we go.

Answer (score 0):

I recently installed XP SP3 on an old MacBook Pro 1,1 15" Core Duo (running OS X 10.6.8) for Boot Camp you must use the Snow Leopard original install/upgrade DVD (post XP install) which includes the Boot Camp 3.0.4 drivers for XP 32 bit.  AFAICT the Apple Boot Camp 3.2 "update" drivers are the last that were compatible with XP 32bit SP3 (note you must be running SP3 and install the 3.0.4 drivers off the OSX Snow Leopard DVD in XP post first boot in order to get everything working).

Answer (score -1):

Boot into Windows and insert Leopard DVD, you will see the Boot Camp drivers installer on the disk :-)